# Too many sub-queries, that I am already confused and I am still missing one column - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following query that has no errors:

```
SELECT u.user_name, u.user_lastn, outer_s.movie_id, outer_s.times_rented
FROM users u,
    ( 
        SELECT * FROM  
        (   
            SELECT user_id, movie_id, count (movie_id) as times_rented
            FROM movie_queue 
            GROUP BY (user_id, movie_id)
            ORDER BY user_id, movie_id 
        ) inner_s
        WHERE times_rented>1
    ) outer_s    
WHERE u.user_id= outer_s.user_id;
```

This is what it returns:

```
USER_NAME                USER_LASTN                 MOVIE_ID TIMES_RENTED
------------------------ ------------------------ ---------- ------------
John                     Smith                             1            3 
John                     Smith                             6            2 
Mary                     Berman                            4            2 
Mary                     Berman                            6            4 
Elizabeth                Johnson                           1            2 
Peter                    Quigley                           2            2
```

What I still need to do is to show the **name of the movie**, instead of the **movie_id**, but
the name of the movies are located in another table named movies that is similar to the
following sample:

```
 MOVIE_ID  MOVIE_NAME                                                
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial    
         2 Jurassic Park                
         3 Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal     
         4 War of the Worlds  
         5 Signs
```

**Desired result:**
What I want to see in the final table are the following columns:
**USER_NAME**  |  **USER_LASTN**  |   **MOVIE_NAME** |  **TIMES_RENTED**  |

**Question:**
But after all the many subqueries I am very confused, how can I get the movie_name there instead of the movie_id?

**Attempted:**
I tried getting the desired result by changing the query to

```
SELECT u.user_name, u.user_lastn, m.movie_name, outer_s.times_rented
FROM users u, movie m (etc.....)
```

But It returned 120 rows instead of the 6 I should get.

Help please!!

Comment: I just got it!!!!.. This worked -->
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, u.user_lastn, m.movie_id, m.movie_name, outer_s.times_rented
from users u, movie m,
( select * from  (   
    select user_id, movie_id, count (movie_id) as times_rented
      from movie_queue 
      group by (user_id, movie_id)
      order by user_id, movie_id 
    ) inner_s
where times_rented>1
) outer_s

where u.user_id= outer_s.user_id AND m.movie_id=outer_s.movie_id ;


But comments on how to improve it are welcome!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_name, u.user_lastn, m.movie_name, COUNT(q.movie_id)
FROM users AS u
JOIN movie_queue AS q ON q.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN movie AS m ON m.movie_id = q.movie_id
GROUP BY u.user_name, u.user_lastn, m.movie_name
HAVING COUNT(q.movie_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join the results of your query to the other query.  However, first, I'm going to rewrite the query to simplify it an use proper join syntax:

```
SELECT u.user_name, u.user_lastn, m.movie_name, outer_s.movie_id, outer_s.times_rented
FROM users u join
     (SELECT user_id, movie_id, count (movie_id) as times_rented
      FROM movie_queue 
      GROUP BY (user_id, movie_id)
      having  count (movie_id) > 1
     ) outer_s    
     on u.user_id= outer_s.user_id join
     movies m
     on outer_s.movie_id = m.move_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use CTEs to make your the query readable:

```
WITH outer_s as (SELECT user_id, movie_id, count (movie_id) as times_rented
      FROM movie_queue 
      GROUP BY (user_id, movie_id)
      having  count (movie_id) > 1
     ) 
SELECT u.user_name, u.user_lastn, m.movie_name, outer_s.movie_id, outer_s.times_rented FROM users u join outer_s    
         on u.user_id= outer_s.user_id join
         movies m
         on outer_s.movie_id = m.move_id
```

Using a CTE offers the advantages of improved readability and ease in maintenance of complex queries. The query can be divided into separate, simple, logical building blocks. These simple blocks can then be used to build more complex, interim CTEs until the final result set is generated.